# About triviality of a path in Residue Theorem

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, compactness, curves, residue-calculus

Reading the [Residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) in the following form :

> Theorem : Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ open, $f: D - S \longmapsto \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic, $S$ closed and discret in $D$.
>
> Let $R \subseteq D$ compact with $C^{1}$ boundary. $R \cap S = \left\lbrace z_{1},\cdots, z_{k}\right\rbrace$ is finite and $\partial R \cap S = \varnothing$
>
> Then we have $\int_{\partial R}f(z)dz = 2\pi i \sum\limits_{1 \leq i \leq k} Res(f,z_{i})$.

I've stumble across the following problem :

(Adding a picture to clarity)

[image]

Let $\beta = \gamma \ast l_{k} \ast \bar{\alpha_{k}} \ast \bar{l_{k}} \ast l_{k-1} \ast \cdots \ast l_{1} \ast \alpha_{1} \ast \bar{l_{1}}$

Where for example $\bar{\alpha_{k}}$ denote the inverse path of $\alpha_{k}$, i.e $\alpha_{k}(1-t)$, and each $\alpha_{i}$ denotes a little circumference around $z_{i}$ traveled counterclockwise.

What I don't get is why $\beta$ is homotopically trivial in $R - \left\lbrace z_{1},\cdots, z_{k}\right\rbrace$. I have the same problem with the proof of [Laurent expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) of homolorphic function on [Annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics)).

I think the reasoning are the same, which should be that $\beta$ runs through a disk, so it's hotopically trivial in $R - \left\lbrace z_{1},\cdots, z_{k}\right\rbrace$.

There is a topological way to see this fact ? I would like to avoid proofs that require any stronger  characterization.

The assert to prove is very clear from the picture I attached, but it doesn't seem trivial or obvious to me prooving it.

Comment: If you want to prove this a bit more formally, you could take one of the line segments and "split" it into two line segments... one going forward, the other going backward. "Pushing" these apart, you can then connect any point inside your internal circle to the point infinity via a line segment not intersecting $\beta$, so both must lie in the same connected component of the complement of $\beta$. In other words, letting the "interior" denote the bounded connected component,  we know $\beta$ is contractible in the interior.

Comment: To fully formalize this argument, you must appeal to the Jordan Curve Theorem and show we can actually "split" the line segment. The former is... hard, and the latter really depends on how picky you want to get... you could replace the circles with rectangles via homotopy then explicitly find a homotopy between the split and joined diagrams in terms of parametrizations of these rectangles, but that sounds absolutely awful. I think at some point you just say "these things are clearly homotopic via a straight-line homotopy which I do not want to write down explicitly"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we want to prove this lemma:

> **Lemma:** Consider two concentric circumferences in the plane centered in the origin parametrized by $A(t)=ae^{2\pi it}$ and $B(t)=be^{2\pi i (1-t)}$ with $a,b\in \mathbb R^+$, $a>b$ and $t\in [0,1]$. Consider the segment $l(t)=bt + (1-t)a$ with $t\in [0,1]$. Then $\gamma(t) = A(t) * l(t) * B(t) * l(1-t)$ is homotopy trivial in $\mathbb R^2  \ \backslash \  {(0,0)}$.

**Proof:** The idea is to rotate around the origin. At each moment $s$ you don't want all the Annulus, but just a piece of it. For, define the following path:
\begin{gather}
A_s(t)=ae^{2\pi i [(1-s)t+s]}\\
B_s(t)=be^{2\pi i [(1-s)(1-t)+s]}\\
l_s(t)=tae^{2\pi s} + (1-t)be^{2\pi i s}
\end{gather}
They are respectively the parametrization of a part of the largest circumference (from the point $ae^{2\pi i s}$ to $a$), the parametrization of a part of the smallest circumference (from the point $b$ to $be^{2\pi i s}$) and the segment that joins $be^{2\pi s}$ and $ae^{2\pi s}$.

Consider now the path $\gamma_s = A_s(t) * l(t) * B_s(t) * l_s(t)$. and define the map:
$$
F:I^2\rightarrow \mathbb R^2 \quad F(t,s) = \gamma_s(t)
$$
This is an homotopy between $\gamma_0 = \gamma$ in our hypotesis, and the path $\gamma_1(t)$ that is:
$$
\gamma_1(t) = ae^{2\pi i} * l(t) * be^{2\pi i} * l(1-t)
$$
and this is homotopy trivial since $ae^{2\pi i}$ and $be^{2\pi i}$ are constant and $l(1-t)$ is the inverse of $l(t)$.

---

Observe that you can choose $\gamma$ as a bunch of $k$ path where the path $\eta_i$ goes only around the point $z_i$ and it is a simple curve (without intersection). This is clearly possible because the points $z_i$ are a discrete set.

Take now the space that $\eta_i$ bounds and its boundary $\eta_i$: this portion of space is omeomorphic to a circle minus a point. Using the lemma and returning back thanks to the omeomorphism you have the statement.